# What are efficient and secure Java RPC options?

Tags: java, rpc

I'm looking for good Java RPC mechanisms that are

- Secure
- Efficient (Fast)

What are the options other than RMI?

Comment: Secure against what kind of threat (interception, interruption, fabrication, modification)? Or do you mean secure as in reliable, fault tolerant? And what kind of tradeoff point do you want? Whatever is maximally fast isn't going to be maximally secure, in whatever meaning you're after.

Comment: If you need to go through proxies and firewalls, your options may be significantly reduced in terms of protocols.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider how you will integrate this RPC stack in your code, for instance, if you are using spring framework, you should have a look at the [supported remoting protocols](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html).
This will also give you some starting point to investigate on different RPC protocols.

One of the key point for performance of RPC is what kind of serialization is used underneath, have a look to [this page](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking) for serialization API performance comparison.

Regards